# CACHE_TRANSIENT is the default caching method in Timber. What does it actualy mean?

Tags: wordpress, caching, timber

[Performance/Caching](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/performance/) section of the docs isn't clear enough. It says that the default caching mode is `Timber\Loader::CACHE_TRANSIENT` , but there's no explanation on what does it really mean.

I know that I can disable it or change caching mode using the `timber/cache/mode` filter, but what does default caching mode actually mean?

Does it mean that all queries are cached using transients by default? It would be weird if all queries were cached in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you render a .twig file, Twig compiles all the HTML tags and variables into the corresponding function calls and echo statements that actually gets run by PHP. It is this blob of data which is stored in the transient, by default, to save processor cycles on page views.

https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/75bb47223e32b787fd74e92f692f9fc34dec7e74/lib/Loader.php#L69

```
if ( false === $output || null === $output ) {
    $twig = $this->get_twig();
    if ( strlen($file) ) {
        $loader = $this->get_loader();
        $result = $loader->getCacheKey($file);
        do_action('timber_loader_render_file', $result);
    }
    $data = apply_filters('timber_loader_render_data', $data);
    $data = apply_filters('timber/loader/render_data', $data, $file);
    $template = $twig->load($file);
    $output = $template->render($data);
}

if ( false !== $output && false !== $expires && null !== $key ) {
    $this->delete_cache();
    $this->set_cache($key, $output, self::CACHEGROUP, $expires, $cache_mode);
}
```

Comment: I don't ask about the differences between object cache and transients. My question is about what does it mean that Timber, by default, uses transients for caching. What is actually cached by default?

Is there anything cached under the good? Or does it only mean that if we use timber caching explicitly then it will use transients?

Comment: From a quick look at the source code it appears as transcients are used by default: https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/75bb47223e32b787fd74e92f692f9fc34dec7e74/lib/Loader.php#L46

Comment: I know that transients are used by default - I included this information in my initial post. The thing is that, from the docs, it's hard to tell what does it meant that transients are used by default. For what they are used? What (if anything?) is being cached by default?

Answer (score 0):

I was actually wondering the same thing myself, so I did some digging into the actual classes and this is what I found.

In `Timber\Loader`, the method `set_cache` calls built in Wordpress caching functions depending on the mode:

1. Timber\Loader::CACHE_TRANSIENT == [set_transient](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/)($trans_key, $value, $expires);

   - Saves a normal transient to database.
2. Timber\Loader::CACHE_SITE_TRANSIENT == [set_site_transient](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_site_transient/)($trans_key, $value, $expires);

   - Same as `set_transient`, but works across multi-site.
3. Timber\Loader::CACHE_OBJECT == [wp_cache_set](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_set/)($key, $value, $group, $expires);

   - Uses `WP_Object_Cache` to save to memory and is non-persistent.

So it appears it’s usually best to just leave it as the default. Your best performance improvements will actually come by caching the results of expensive queries using `TimberHelper::transient` ([see example](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/performance/#cache-the-php-data)). The default template caches produced by Twig are actually pretty performant as-is.

Comment: Just want to clarify, the main reason you don’t normally want to cache items within the templates themselves by using the {% cache %} tag is because that actually produces another round trip to the database. The untouched templates are file-based and should be faster, even if PHP has to do some work. The caveat is, if you are producing Twig code that has queries embedded in (i.e. a CPT query).